# What is the function of different Oracle ASM disk groups?

Tags: oracle

I have three disks. **OCR**, **DATA** and **FRA**.

What is the function of **OCR**?
I understand **DATA** is where all the database files are kept together with the temp files and redo logs and **FRA** is where archive logs and backups are kept but OCR is what I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCR stands for Oracle Cluster Registry, which is the place where Oracle cluster processes store and manipulate data related to the cluster. And as the question itself says, in ASM these are not single disks put usually a bunch of disks or disk partitions.